# Select input hidden value inside a div

Tags: jquery, select, input

```js
$('.aggiungi_play').click(function() {

  // find the class
  pulsante_aggiungi = $(this);

  //find the prev class where next I write a ajax content
  spazio_canzone = pulsante_aggiungi.prev('.titolo_autore_codice_selezionata');

  // find next div
  div_right_click = $(this).next('.click_play_right');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/query_temp_inserita_play.php",
    data: {
      id_cella_canzone_selezionata: id_cella_canzone_selezionata
    },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(scrivo_canzone) {

      JSON.stringify(scrivo_canzone); //to string

      // scrivo il titolo della canzone
      $(spazio_canzone).html(scrivo_canzone.titolo_autore_temp);

    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Sovraccarico del server. Clicca ok e poi ritenta. Grazie");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="spazio_canzoni_playlist bg-warning">
  <div class="orario_playlist">12:40</div>
  <div class="titolo_autore_codice_selezionata">TEXT - TEXT</div>
  <div class="aggiungi_play" rel="4157">
    <div class="btn btn-danger btn-md">Inserisci</div>
  </div>
  <div class="click_play_right start">
    <input type="hidden" class="canzone_file" value="value to find">
  </div>
</div>
```

So I want to find the input value closest, next in this hidden input I want write my new content with ajax function.
I want to find this value

```
<input type="hidden" class="canzone_file" value="value to find">
```

So my problem is select that input file
I try with next, nextAll, find, closest but nothing

how can get it and then write in this the new value?
Then with the ajax function I want to write a new value into the field

```
<input type="hidden" class="canzone_file" value="value to find">
```

thanks

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking._

Comment: Than I want to select the input field and write a content

Comment: which value of them ?!!

Comment: <input type="hidden" class="canzone_file" value="value to find">

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use next and find like :

```js
$('.aggiungi_play').click(function() {
    console.log( $(this).next('.click_play_right').find('.canzone_file').val() );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spazio_canzoni_playlist bg-warning">
  <div class="orario_playlist">12:40</div>
  <div class="titolo_autore_codice_selezionata">TEXT - TEXT</div>
  <div class="aggiungi_play" rel="4157">
    <div class="btn btn-danger btn-md">Inserisci</div>
  </div>
  <div class="click_play_right start">
    <input type="hidden" class="canzone_file" value="value to find">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I find the error in my code...
I missed some " in my code!
now it works!

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks bro!